# Rails -- gem installation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Quick question about gem installation -- when I use `bundle install` I know it installs the gems necessary for my individual project, but it doesn't affect other projects on my computer.  If I use `gem install name_of_gem` would that also only affect the current project or would it affect all projects on my computer using rails (a generic installation)?  In general I think I am a little confused about how exactly gem installation works, so if your answer could include some general background information to help me understand this that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, gems are typically installed system-wide, or in your home directory is this is not possible. By default, when your application uses a gem, RubyGems loads the latest installed version. If you want to use a specific version, RubyGems lets you do that with this syntax:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'RedCloth', '3.0'
```

Bundler is a helpful tool that tracks the versions of a gem that are being used to develop a project, and then allows you to both install them in one fell swoop with `bundle install`, and also to load those exact versions. The application loads them by loading the Bundler code, which overrides parts of RubyGems to use the versions specified in the Gemfile.

By default, Bundler just calls RubyGems to install gems (again, system-wide or in your homedir). You can ask it to store the gems in a directory called `vendor/cache` by using `bundle package`. This lets you "freeze" the gems so that you can distribute them with the source code.

If you want further isolation of your Ruby environments, you should use [RVM](https://rvm.io), which lets you set up isolated gemsets, and in fact, different versions of Ruby, to use on different projects. When you're using RVM, the directory where RubyGems installs things is overridden and is specific to your current Ruby version and gemset.

I'd recommend reading the docs for both [RubyGems](http://docs.rubygems.org/) and [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/); they're both quite good.

Answer (score 1):

When you do bundle install the gems **are** installed at rubygems and would be available for all your projects unless you're using [RVM](https://rvm.io) and setting up gemsets for your projects.

When you're not using RVM and you do a **gem install** your operating system is probably going to install the gem at your current user's files (usually ~/.gem), if you **sudo install gem** it's going to install wherever is the place your system Ruby is installed.

I would really recommend you to setup RVM do manage separate groups of gems and rubies. You can read their website linked above or [a simple tutorial I wrote to use it](http://techbot.me/2011/01/handling-various-rubies-at-the-same-time-in-your-machine-with-rvm-%E2%80%93-ruby-version-manager/).

Comment: So in my case one project is using Rake 0.9.2 and I want to switch to Rake 0.8.7.  However, a second project I want to keep at Rake 0.9.2.  If I just use `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2` and then `bundle update` where in the bundle I specified rake 0.8.7, will this also affect my second project dependent on rake 0.9.2?  And if so how do I resolve this?

Comment: @Kvass: RVM is a good choice for this case. If you wanted to, you could specify it in your Gemfile and use `bundle exec rake` instead (I believe this works; haven't checked). But Bundler is intended for dependency management, not environment isolation. If you want the latter, you should use RVM. RVM and Bundler work quite well together, fortunately.

Comment: Does rvm work on windows / where can I find a windows guide for using it?

Comment: The closest Windows equivalent is apparently Pik: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/ . I haven't used it myself, though, since I typically do Ruby development on OS X or Linux.